# CSS stylesheet not updating any changes from PHP template

Tags: php, css, templates

Okay, so I tried to get help for this issue with my host-provider (Bluehost) which was a big mistake because they are totally incompetent and only wasted about 20 minutes of my time.

For this issue, please see: http://blnr.org/fantasia

I've developed a PHP template (http://blnr.org/fantasia/files/template.php) and am calling it in each individual page I create. This is working fine, and everything is running smoothly.

Now, for some unknown reason, whenever I make any updates to my stylesheet (http://blnr.org/fantasia/files/css/style.css), nothing is updating. For example, I've changed the top comment line in the sheet from "Constructors" to "Global" and when I reload the sheet, nothing has been updated.

I can't figure out why this is occurring and am looking for some help!

Comment: How are you updating your stylesheet? Are doing it on your computer or using Bluehost's editor in the file manager?

Comment: I am updating it via FTP

Comment: It isn't a browser cache issue as I don't see the change in your stylesheet either and I've never visited your site before. Are you sure you're uploading the correct file to the correct place?

Comment: It isn't a ftp-client issue? Like settings "don't overwrite existing files". Try to  restart the ftp-client and upload file(s) again.

Comment: It looks like it was an FTP issue, fixed!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it was an FTP issue, perhaps a timeout or something although everything appeared to be uploading. I'm using WinSCP and I've heard it has some issues

Answer (score 0):

More likely then not you are dealing with a browser cache issue.

You can determine if this is being cached on the browser by clearing your cache. then reloading.

If you need to force your css to be reloaded then there is a technique called cache busting that involves adding a query string to the end of your stylesheet include that you change when you change the css file.

```
  <link rel='stylesheet' href="/styles/site.css?version=1"/>
```

This will cause the browser to see it as a different resource and it will effectively invalidate the browser's copy.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that and still not updating. Could it be a cache on the server side?

Comment: I can't see the change the OP made to the CSS file either despite never having visited the site before so I don't believe it's a browser cache issue.

Comment: it the css being dynamically created? Another option is that it could be being cache by an intermediary server.

Comment: cache busted reload yielded same results

Comment: The CSS file is static so it isn't a server side caching issue. Personally, I think the OP isn't uploading the file correctly or is doing so to the wrong directory.

Comment: that is likely the case. @blnr try uploading a style2.css into the same directory and navigate to it via http://blnr.org/fantasia/files/css/style2.css